# C++11 thread doesn't work with virtual member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to get a class run a thread, which will call a virtual member function named Tick() in a loop. Then I tried to derive a class and override the base::Tick().

but when execute, the program just call the base class's Tick instead of override one. any solutions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Runnable {
 public:
  Runnable() : running_(ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false)) {

   }
  ~Runnable() { 
    if (running_)
      thread_.join();
  }
  void Stop() { 
    if (std::atomic_exchange(&running_, false))
      thread_.join();
  }
  void Start() {
    if (!std::atomic_exchange(&running_, true)) {
      thread_ = std::thread(&Runnable::Thread, this);
    }
  }
  virtual void Tick() {
    cout << "parent" << endl;
  };
  std::atomic<bool> running_;

 private:
  std::thread thread_;
  static void Thread(Runnable *self) {
    while(self->running_) {
      self->Tick();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
  }
};

class Fn : public Runnable {
 public:
  void Tick() {
    cout << "children" << endl;
  }
};

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  Fn fn;
  fn.Start();
  return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
parent
```

Comment: Personally, I think resolving this problem is not the best solution. I think the best solution is to not create this problem in the first place. This is a lousy solution to a non-problem.

Comment: Don't write Java in C++.

Comment: You are right. I made this for capturing system, which will query a few sources in a constant frequency, say 10 times / sec, and pull data to queues. and there is a monitor will pull from queues at another constant freq and display the data. So this is the solution I came up with, make a base class, and then use a vector/list to hold all the sources and monitor (while the sources may add/remove at runtime). Any better solutions?

Comment: Something like `std::function` can give you the polymorphism you need.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: This is not even *Java*, in *Java* `Runnable` is an interface that get's passed to a `Thread` object for execution. Java also has the model of deriving from `Thread` similar to the approach in the question, but the recommendation is not to use it. The design is flawed.

Comment: @xiaoyi: The actual problem to *solve*, which you stated in the comment above, should be part of the *question*. At this point, it probably makes no sense, since it would turn the existing answers invalid --the *real* question is not what you asked, and the answers would not answer that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't let an object run out of scope until you're finished using it! The `return 0;` at the end of `main` causes `fn` to go out of scope. So by the time you get around to calling `tick`, there's no guarantee the object even exists any more.

(The logic in `~Runnable` is totally broken. Inside the destructor is way too late -- the object is already at least partially destroyed.)

Comment: What object doesn't exist anymore? The destructor joins the thread. If the thread is running, the object exists.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: The destructor of the *parent* joins the thread, but at that time the object is no longer a child.

Comment: The **Runnable** destructor joins the thread. That's too late as the actual object the thread is running on (the `fn` object) has already been destroyed. (Answer updated.)

Comment: Can be easily tested with a sleep right before the return. But probably this is the explanation. Good spot!

Comment: thanks a lot, you are right. that's the problem. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @xiaoyi: I recommend creating the object with `new` and letting the thread destroy it itself. Alternatively, you can use a reference-counted object and let the thread hold a reference. One other choice is to use a 'monitor' object that's separate from the thread object. The destructor of the monitor can join the thread which then deletes its own thread object.

Comment: @xiaoyi: Redesign, combining the thread control and the code that is executing in a single hierarchy is a bad approach to a design. These are two different concepts, what executes and what is being executed, and inheritance is not the proper way of managing it. Consider alternative approaches like composition, or just using the C++ thread library as in any of the multiple examples that you will find around: no inheritance.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks, how about I make a class called Ticker which have a virtual Tick() function, and a class called Controller holds a unique_ptr to a Ticker instance, and the Controller holds a thread and calls ticker->Tick()?

Comment: @xiaoyi: That could work (you don't even need the `unique_ptr`, it could be a member if you write a template. Note that the problem is with the thread control vs. the code that executes. You might want to separate thread control, frequency control and actual code to be executed in three different layers. The code to be executed can be bound into a `function<result()>`, the frequency control would contain a loop that controls timing and calls that. The thread would execute that frequency control. The thread control would signal it to stop and join the thread. You don't even need a type for this

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I have opened another question, So if you want , we may continue there, and give you some credits. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10635365/245428 :D

Answer (score 6):

The approach of using inheritance with the parent serving as *control* for the thread and the children *implementing* the functions is a bad idea in general. The common problems with this approach come from construction and destruction:

- if the thread is started from the constructor in the parent (control) then it might start running before the constructor completes and the thread might call the virtual function before the complete object has been fully constructed
- if the thread is stopped in the destructor of the parent, then by the time that the control joins the thread, the thread is executing a method on an object that does no longer exist.

In your particular case you are hitting the second case. The program starts executing, and in `main` the second thread is started. At that point there is a race between the main thread and the newly launched, if the new thread is faster (unlikely, as starting the thread is an expensive operation), it will call the member method `Tick` that will be dispatched to the final overrider `Fn::Tick`.

But if the main thread is faster it will exit the scope of `main`, and it will start destruction of the object, it will complete destruction of the `Fn` object and during construction of the `Runnable` it will `join` the thread. If the main thread is fast enough, it will make it to the `join` before the second thread and wait there for the second thread to call `Tick` on the *now* final overrider that is `Runnable::Tick`. Note that this is *Undefined Behavior*, and not guaranteed, since the second thread is accessing an object that is being destroyed.

Also, there are other possible orderings, like for example, the second thread could dispatch to `Fn::Tick` before the main thread starts destruction, but might not complete the function before the main thread destroys the `Fn` sub object, in which case your second thread would be calling a member function on a dead object.

You should rather follow the approach in the C++ standard: separate the *control* from the *logic*, fully construct the object that will be run and pass it to the thread during construction. Note that this is the case of Java's `Runnable`, which is recommended over extending the `Thread` class. Note that from a design point of view this separation makes sense: the *thread* object manages the execution, and the *runnable* is the code to execute.
A thread is not a *ticker*, but rather what controls the execution of the *ticker*. And in your code `Runnable` is not something that can be run, but rather something that *runs* other objects that happen to derive from it.