# How to use C++11 <thread> designing a system which pulls data from sources

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, c++11

This question comes from:
[C++11 thread doesn't work with virtual member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634603/c11-thread-doesnt-work-with-virtual-member-function)

As suggested in a comment, my question in previous post may not the right one to ask, so here is the original question:

I want to make a capturing system, which will query a few sources in a constant/dynamic frequency (varies by sources, say 10 times / sec), and pull data to each's queues. while the sources are not fixed, they may add/remove during run time.

and there is a monitor which pulls from queues at a constant freq and display the data.

So what is the best design pattern or structure for this problem.

I'm trying to make a list for all the sources pullers, and each puller holds a thread, and a  specified pulling function (somehow the pulling function may interact with the puller, say if the source is drain, it will ask to stop the pulling process on that thread.)

Comment: Here are two links that may help you. This is a typical Producer-Consumer problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/pattern_synopses.htm#Concurrency%20Patterns

Comment: Thanks. I'm using balking pattern in queues. I'm looking for some pattern for system wide design.

Comment: Some extra information that impacts the design: How strict are your real time requirements? How long does it take to query each source? How many sources are there? How many at each frequency?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Some sources's tick time is dynamic, ranged from 15-60 ticks/sec (capture time ranged from 10ms to 60ms). And others are static (frequency is defined when start), ranged from 25-30 ticks/sec (capture time lower than 10ms). And monitor will pulling at at a constant frequency of 30 ticks/sec. The number of sources should no more than 30 (based on the host's number of cores.)

Comment: @xiaoyi, ok, but we dont have enough info about the rest of the system to be able to answer much more.

Comment: That does not answer any of the questions: How strict are the real time requirements (do you need to poll at about 20Hz, or exactly every 50ms?), how long are the query operations (does it take 1ms to poll each source, or can it take .2s?) How many sources do you have (are there a few 10? many 100s? a lot 1000s?) How many at each frequency (assuming low rt constraints, is the time it takes to poll all of the 20Hz sources greater than 50ms?) These questions try to resolve how many threads you need/can afford for each source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the operation where you query a source is blocking (or you have *lots* of them), you don't *need* to use threads for this. We could start with a `Producer` which will work with either synchronous or asynchronous (threaded) dispatch:

```
template <typename OutputType>
class Producer
{
    std::list<OutputType> output;

protected:
    int poll_interval; // seconds? milliseconds?
    virtual OutputType query() = 0;

public:
    virtual ~Producer();

    int next_poll_interval() const { return poll_interval; }
    void poll() { output.push_back(this->query()); }

    std::size_t size() { return output.size(); }
    // whatever accessors you need for the queue here:
    // pop_front, swap entire list, etc.
};
```

Now we can derive from this `Producer` and just implement the `query` method in each subtype. You can set `poll_interval` in the constructor and leave it alone, or change it on every call to `query`.  There's your general producer component, with no dependency on the dispatch mechanism.

```
template <typename OutputType>
class ThreadDispatcher
{
    Producer<OutputType> *producer;
    bool shutdown;
    std::thread thread;

    static void loop(ThreadDispatcher *self)
    {
        Producer<OutputType> *producer = self->producer;

        while (!self->shutdown)
        {
            producer->poll();
            // some mechanism to pass the produced values back to the owner
            auto delay = // assume millis for sake of argument
                std::chrono::milliseconds(producer->next_poll_interval());
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
        }
    }

public:
    explicit ThreadDispatcher(Producer<OutputType> *p)
      : producer(p), shutdown(false), thread(loop, this)
    {
    }

    ~ThreadDispatcher()
    {
        shutdown = true;
        thread.join();
    }

    // again, the accessors you need for reading produced values go here
    // Producer::output isn't synchronised, so you can't expose it directly
    // to the calling thread
};
```

This is a quick sketch of a simple dispatcher that would run your producer in a thread, polling it however often you ask it to. Note that passing produced values back to the owner isn't shown, because I don't know how you want to access them.

Also note I haven't synchronized access to the shutdown flag - it should probably be atomic, but it might be implicitly synchronized by whatever you choose to do with the produced values.

With this organization, it'd also be easy to write a synchronous dispatcher to query multiple producers in a single thread, for example from a select/poll loop, or using something like Boost.Asio and a deadline timer per producer.